# How to allow copying message on MessageBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How can I allow selecting and copying of text from MessageBox in WPF?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

If you don't need *selecting text* as a requirement, just use System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox. It maps to the system-default one which already allows copying its contents with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: --> Total Nitpick <-- WinForms is not WPF.  This is a really great trick though.

Comment: A.R.: It's still part of .NET and in most cases you can get away with mixing them (and it's not as if this uses any WinForms controls in WPF or similar).

Comment: This may be the best answer using a *standard* .NET "MessageBox", but I think the ideal solution (and the one that would *literally* answer the O.P.'s Q) would be a message box that works like those displayed by Visual Studio where the user can mark any part or all of the text in them as if all the text were in some borderless read-only "TextBox" on the Form with the same background color as the Form. I think Microsoft developed some custom "MessageBox" for that that they're not sharing with us in .NET.

Answer (score 29):

You can just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while the message box has focus, but it will give you a lot more text than just the error message.

e.g.

```
    MessageBox.Show("Message", "Message Title", MessageBoxButton.OK);
```

Would copy and paste as:

```
    ---------------------------
    Message Title 
    ---------------------------
    Message
    ---------------------------
    OK   
    ---------------------------
```

Comment: Mind blown a decade later. How have I not ever come across this before???

Answer (score 14):

### I did it this way:

```
string msgtext = "message text";
if (MessageBox.Show(msgtext, "bla bla bla. (OK to copy)", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
  { Clipboard.SetText(msgtext); }
```

---

It works pretty good.

Comment: for WPF: `if (msgtext, "bla bla bla. (OK to copy)", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Information) == MessageBoxResult.OK)`

Comment: I tweaked this suggestion a little to use Yes/No. `var response = MessageBox.Show("...\r\n\r\nCopy to clipboard?", "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);` and then `if (response == MessageBoxResult.Yes) { ClipBoard.SetText("..."); }`

Answer (score 7):

If you're displaying the messagebox...

```
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(messageToShowInMsgBoxString, true);
```

will copy the item to the clipboard.

Comment: It's not very nice to clobber the user's clipboard, though.

Comment: Yeah, but you could add that to a button click event so that it only copies if they choose to.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach would be to use a Window with a selectable text control, like a textbox for example.  I can say from experience that this is the easiest way, and will not take much time or code changes to implement.